# Activity indicator is not visible on screen

Tags: progress-bar, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

I am working on xamarin.forms. I need to do some tasks that takes some time. So I want to use an activity indicator. So before starting the task I put IsEnabled and IsVisible property true for activitiy indicator. And after completing the task I changed its value to false.

But when i am trying to run it, the activity indicator is not visible. The task completes successfully but during that period I can not do any thing on screen and activity indicator is also not visible.

I want when tasks start activity indicator should visible and after completing the task it should disable. I think this is some thread that I should manage so that UI thread work properly and activity indicator starts to visible.

Please update me if any one knows how to manage it?

Comment: Could be a Xamarin.Forms bug, what platform are you running on?

Comment: You need to provide some code that shows what you've tried. It's almost impossible to diagnose an issue like this without context.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set an await on the process so the indicator runs while the process is ongoing.